# When to include recursion for computing expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

Consider a game where you win \$1 with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ and lose \$1 with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. If you neither win nor lose (i.e. when it's a tie, which has probability $\frac{1}{6}$), the game simply repeats itself. The game ends as soon as you win or lose.

**What is your expected payoff?**

I thought of two approaches to this problem, but they give different results so I am confused as to which one is correct.

- Approach 1

  Let $\mathbb{E}(X)$ denote the expected payoff, then we can write the recurrence
  $$\mathbb{E}(X) = +1 \cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{win}] - 1 \cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{lose}] + \mathbb{P}[\text{repeat}] \cdot \mathbb{E}(X) \\ 
  \mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} \mathbb{E}(X) \\
  \mathbb{E}(X) = -\frac{1}{5}$$
- Approach 2

  However, another approach is to realize that since the game just repeats itself if tied (without any cost), we can simply ignore the probability of a tie and calculate $\mathbb{E}(X)$ by directly comparing probability of winning and losing:
  $$\mathbb{E}(X) = +1 \cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{win}] - 1 \cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{lose}] = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{6}$$

Obviously, these two ways of thinking give different answers. Which one is correct?

Resolved:

As suggested by @lulu, I compared the probabilities incorrectly in approach 2. If we want to "ignore" the probability of a tie, we should adjust $\mathbb{P}(win)$ to $\frac{1/3}{1/3 + 1/2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(lose)$ to $\frac{1/2}{1/3 + 1/2}$, which would have given the same answer as approach 1.

Comment: "Expected payoff" over how many rounds?

Comment: The first approach is correct and the second approach is not. You can't ignore the probability of a tie; that's like pretending the $\mathbb{E}(X)$ term in the first sum is zero, which it's not.

Comment: @lulu the game ends as soon as you win or lose. (updated the post).

Comment: But then "ties" don't mean much.  Just adjust the probabilities.  You win with probability $\frac {1/3}{1/3+1/2}=\frac 25$.

Comment: You need to compute the conditional probabilities. That is, the expected value given that you did not tie. This will be equivalent to the first calculation.

Comment: @lulu Ah I see. So the correct way to compare the probability of winning versus losing is $\mathbb{P}(win) = \frac{1/3}{1/3 + 1/2} = \frac{2}{5}$ and $\mathbb{P}(lose) = \frac{1/2}{1/3+1/2} = \frac{3}{5}$. Therefore, approach 2 should have computed $\mathbb{E}(X)$ via $+ 1 \cdot \frac{2}{5} - 1 \cdot \frac{3}{5} = -\frac{1}{5}$, which gives the same answer.
I compared the probabilities incorrectly.

Comment: Right.  $\quad$ $\quad$

Comment: @lulu Thanks. Updated the post to resolve this question.